# Navigation property without foreign key, or fluent api version?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table of users, where a user can be the manager of another user (this is optional, thus `int? IdManager`)

```
[Table("users")]
public partial class User
{
    #region Properties
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region DataNavigation
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation Id for getting parent Field
    /// WARNING: this works, but need to remove foreign key creation in migration file !
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("Manager")]
    [Column("IdManager")]
    public int? IdManager { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation object to parent Field
    /// </summary>
    [ScriptIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Now in code first, the above code generates this

```
public partial class manager : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("users", "IdManager", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("users", "IdManager");
        AddForeignKey("users", "IdManager", "users", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("users", "IdManager", "users");
        DropIndex("users", new[] { "IdManager" });
        DropColumn("users", "IdManager");
    }
}
```

However it breaks while updating the database with `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

But if i delete the foreign key creation

```
public partial class manager : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("users", "IdManager", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("users", "IdManager");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("users", new[] { "IdManager" });
        DropColumn("users", "IdManager");
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in dbContext and Linq

...but, i have to leave `[ForeignKey("Manager")]` on my user object (for linq & dbcontext), which is not so good, since at a later time it will certainly blow up in someones face again.

Any idea on how i can map this properly either via Data Attributes or fluent api ?

Thanks!

Comment: The above code actually works, there was an error in the migration history where when migrations failed, not all changes where reverted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the other way, created one such `Employee` table and added as a model, it got me this:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Subordinates = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("EmployeeDbContext", "dbo");
        HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(50);
        HasMany(p => p.Subordinates).WithOptional(p => p.Manager)
                                 .HasForeignKey(p => p.ManagerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code i posted works fine when referencing one table to another, nullable just means a zero or one relationship which is fine, but breaks when referencing within the same table (problem i'm having)

Comment: Nice man. I'm sure this works, unfortunately you switched the main key from Identity to None, and autoincrement will not work anymore like this. It still generates the `AddForeignKey("users", "IdManager", "users", "Id");` and is pretty much the same as adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to the primary key of my code above, but which unfortunately supresses autoincrement handling

Comment: Updated my code to show `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on the primary key, since this is the default behavior when not specifying anything

Comment: i changed it to `idenity` and filled some rows manually in db. works

Comment: Not sure what i just did, but cleaned up some migrations, made sure all values on the table where correct: Id = PK, NN, AI, and reran the migration. Now it took the foreign key ! Your code actually generates the exact same code as mine with Data Annotations. But i'll consider this as the answer since it's a nice example of doing it with fluent api, and i'm glad you kept insisting since things worked out ! btw nice touch with subordinates ..i'm gonna be adding that since i'm sure it will be of great use. Thanks man

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested it, but in fluent api it should be like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasOptional(u=>u.Manager)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(u=>u.IdManager)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So, a User has an optional Manager, which can have many users linking to it without the Manager having a collection of Users (WithMany without parameters), with the given foreign key property (IdManager) and with cascade delete disabled.

Comment: Pretty close ! This code works fine as far as mapping goes, but now database migrations will not generate the necessary `IdManager` column in the database. I'm worried when someone tries to generate the whole model without any migration history, and either exceptions get thrown, or necessary fields are not generated in the database.

Comment: It doesn't? What does it generate?

Comment: it generates an empty up() & down() ..but if i create `IdManager` in the database manually, dbcontext & linq works fine

Comment: Ah, this must be because the change in the mapping doesn't require a change in the db schema, but if you deleted your migrations history and added a new migration, it would create everything correctly, including that column

Comment: Ok, empty stuff was a bug, there was a migration in the database that was not reverted when the constraint crashed. Now the migrations work. Your code produces actually the exact same one as what i get with code first data annotations. Meaning it's trying to add a foreign key constraint, and that crashes the migration with `Cannot add foreign key constraint` :-(

Comment: instead of running `update-database` for your migration, run `update-database -script' command. see what is the sql thats going to run in your sql server. you will find out what is causing error.

Comment: ok will try that, i suspect that since the primary key is Identity it doesn't like that since switching to none works, but you loose autoincrement which is needed on this table. Thanks again

Comment: I upped your answer even if i selected the other as the right one, you code is absolutely correct too. Thanks for the help !